# Sending messages to Azure IOT hub through MQTT protocol using Paho library

Tags: python, mqtt, azure-iot-hub, paho

**Hello All,**

I am trying send telemetry messages to **Azure IOT hub** through **MQTT** protocol (**Using Python**) by using **Paho** library. I have referred to 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support (Microsoft Docs) and followed exactly same steps referred to the document. However I am getting an error while running the code.

Below is the **python code**

```
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt
import ssl

path_to_root_cert = "C:\Python_Files\Digicert_Cert.txt"
device_id = "MyDeviceName"
sas_token = "SharedAccessSignature sr=MyHubName.azure-devices.net&sig=UclWeYtF5WSy4QUvTQvDF1ml2fVze0VFpv4e7YLFdQE%3D&se=1567761926&skn=iothubowner"
iot_hub_name = "MyHubName"

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
  print ("Device connected with result code: " + str(rc))
def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
  print ("Device disconnected with result code: " + str(rc))
def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
  print ("Device sent message")

client = mqtt.Client(client_id=device_id, protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311)

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
client.on_publish = on_publish

client.username_pw_set(username=iot_hub_name+".azure-devices.net/" + device_id, password=sas_token)

client.tls_set(ca_certs=path_to_root_cert, certfile=None, keyfile=None, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, ciphers=None)
client.tls_insecure_set(False)

client.connect(iot_hub_name+".azure-devices.net", port=8883)

client.publish("devices/" + device_id + "/messages/events/", "{id=123}", qos=1)
client.loop_forever()
```

I am getting the below **error** while running the **python code**.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python_Files\Python Script.py", line 27, in <module>
    client.connect(iot_hub_name+".azure-devices.net", port=8883)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 839, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 962, in reconnect
    sock = socket.create_connection((self._host, self._port), source_address=(self._bind_address, 0))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

I am using device explorer tool to generate SAS token. Below is the Screenshot for the same[image]

SAS token I am using in my code is

```
sas_token ="SharedAccessSignature sr=PuneODCIOTHub.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2FMyDotnetDevice&sig=KqyeH0n2kez3Zyz3%2BnVnOVyAsG%2F65MYO95%2FrgdJjBzI%3D&se=1536300480"
```

**Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `sas_token` is incorrect in your post,it does not contain `%2Fdevices%2F{deviceid}`. I don't know how you get the token,but I think you can use [Device Explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer) tool to generate the SAS token.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michael for your time. I have used device explorer tool only to generate SAS token. I have updated my question with the snapshot of generating SAS token using device explorer.

Comment: @HarshadHolkar, are you sure the device id you selected same with the device_id  in your code when you use device explorer to generate SAS token? Please check it. The code works fine for me.

Comment: Yes Michael I am using same device id in code as well as while generating SAS token from Device Explorer.

Comment: Have you checked for firewalls and open ports? Is your network in proxy?

Comment: Yes Michael firewall was the issue... Thank a lot for your help in figuring this out.